# Set the Layout according to the Height of Screen

Tags: android

I am using two ListView in a screen. I want to divide the height of each ListView but I want it to be screen independent. For this I need to know the Height of the screen. I am using xml to do this.
Can any one please help me to achieve this?

Thank You
Deepak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
>
  <ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
  />
  <ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
  />
</LinearLayout>
```

The important parts are having the `ListViews` `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` and the `LinearLayout` `android:orientation="vertical"`

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html#linearlayout) for more information about the layout_weight attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the layout height of the views to "fill parent" and layout weight to 1.